# setting user id with Facebook java script SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-analytics

We are having a hybrid android/iOS app.
Majority of our source code is with HTML/JS.

We are using Google analytics already.
For better user demographics , marketing & re-marketing we want to use Facebook analytics for apps.

Identifying users based on our custom user Id is critical to us. It helps us unify the user behaviour on app & html/js.

I can see that with the android & iOS Facebook SDK we can set the user ID.

Does FB javascript SDK provide api to set user ID?

Answer (score 0):

User properties are not yet supported by the JS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

User properties are now supported by the JS SDK. Documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/properties